# Debugging ASP.NET cloud project over LAN

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, iis-express, azure-cloud-services

I've been trying to debug this ASP.NET cloud project over LAN, because we need it for testing at work. I have done plenty of research on the subject, but I simply cannot get it to work as expected. I think I have narrowed the problem down to being that, **the project is a cloud service project**.

If I create a new ASP.NET MVC project, without the cloud service, it works just fine, when editing the projects bindings, plus turning off the firewall of course. If I then do the same procedure, but with a cloud service project, with the asp.net mvc as the web role, I get **"connection refused"** when trying to access it over LAN.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on and/or how to solve it?

Bindings:

```
<bindings>
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:5807:localhost" />
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:5807:*" />
</bindings>
```

Answer (score 1):

I spent almost a full day at work with exactly the same issue.

It **finally** started to work after I reïnstalled IIS express.

Uninstall at Programs and Features
[image: Uninstall here]

Download the Microsoft Web Platform Installer found at link below:
http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

search for IIS express, and install it.

After that, it worked like a charm for me. I hope it works for you as well, because I wasted way too much time on this problem...